# Is there a way I can contain an image and content in a separate container using HTML / inline CSS / Markdown

Tags: html, css, user-interface, flexbox, grid

Looking to have an image on the left side of a container, however, if the content is too short or too long I'd have to adjust the height of the image proportionally to prevent the content from sliding below the image. The reason I want to contain the Image and the content in the container is to ensure that the image is coherent throughout the entirety of the pages.

We can use HTML / in-line CSS / Markdown to make this adjustment. Perhaps I believe we may need to use Flexbox

I've attached the code below, I've used Grid and a table, and I don't really like it

```
<div style=“display:grid; grid-template-columns:auto 1fr”>
<div>
<h1> <img src=“https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg”
  align=“left”
  hspace=“30"
  width=“100”
  height=“100">
</div>
<div>
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
  Description for Title
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>BLAH:</strong></td>
      <td style=“padding-left:20px”><p>Updates are made annually or more frequently if needed<p/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style=“vertical-align:top”><strong>Contact Us:</strong></td>
      <td style=“padding-left:20px”>
        <ul style=“padding-left: 15px; margin: 0px”>
          <li style=“padding-bottom: 10px”><a href=“mailto:sample@email.com”>Email: Jane Doe</a></li>
          <li><a>Skype: Sample</a></li>
        </ul>
        </br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

--Most Recent 
The image is on the left side but the table seems to overlap the image

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmrSV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit 2

I've edited this again for you if this needs to be inline styles, i've gave a class name on the different containers so you can clearly see how this is working,

your image can just go into `image-container` and your content can go in `content-container`. You can add size to the containers, padding, margin etc.. to adjust the layout that you want, but this should help with the basic setup for your HTML.

```
<div class="main-container" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img
        src=“https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg”
        hspace="30" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <h4>Description for Title</h4>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>BLAH:</strong></td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
              <p>Updates are made annually or more frequently if needed</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;"><strong>Contact Us:</strong></td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
              <ul style="padding-left: 15px; margin: 0;">
                <li style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                  <a href="“mailto:sample@email.com”">Email: Jane Doe</a>
                </li>
                <li><a>Skype: Sample</a></li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Forgot to change your image back to what you had, i had to set one of mine to test

Comment: When using this, the content overlaps the image. I want the image on the left-hand side and the content on the right-hand side of the image, though I want the image to be just one size throughout, not dependant on the size of the content.

Comment: does this still have to be inline css or should i put it in a separate css file

Comment: This has to be inline.

Comment: Updated for you now @MikeAhmed

Comment: This one works better, but the same issue persists. I've inserted the image URL in the post and I'll attach it here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmrSV.png

Comment: does it not fix it if you add a width to your content-container?

Comment: Adjusting the Content Width solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here a flexbox example:

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;">
  <div style="flex: 1 auto;">
    <img src=“https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg” hspace="30" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1 auto;">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Description for Title
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>BLAH:</strong></td>
        <td style=“padding-left:20px”>
          <p>Updates are made annually or more frequently if needed
            <p />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=“vertical-align:top”><strong>Contact Us:</strong></td>
        <td style=“padding-left:20px”>
          <ul style=“padding-left: 15px; margin: 0px”>
            <li style=“padding-bottom: 10px”><a href=“mailto:sample@email.com”>Email: Jane Doe</a></li>
            <li><a>Skype: Sample</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/f04Ldobj/)**

Comment: I appreciate the help, this solution also has the content overlapping the image.